# Multiple macro code writing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I've created a spreadsheet that has a macro that will delete and move to a new tab a row when the status in column A is marked 'paid'. I need to take that one step further so that if the status is marked 'paid' and invoice number in column D matches the same row that all same invoice #s will also be moved to the new tab. the code that I am using is below. The image is a snippit of the spreadsheet. In the example Sarah Phillips has data in rows 9-12 with 'paid' status in column A row 9. I need all 4 that has the same invoice # to move to the new spreadsheet. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70iRu.png)

```
Sub TransferData()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture data and then create a loop in existing code](https://superuser.com/questions/1458398/capture-data-and-then-create-a-loop-in-existing-code)

Answer (score 0):

After `If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then` capture the invoice number of that row.  Then do another `for` loop inside the first one that loops through all the rows and moves all those that match the invoice number.

Edit:  It looks like this works.  Test (on a copy of your data) and change as needed.

```
Sub TransferData()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    ' added:
    Dim invNo As Long

    I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then
            ' added:
            invNo = xRg(K).Offset(0, 3).Value2
            For L = 1 To xRg.Count
                If xRg(L).Offset(0, 3).Value2 = invNo Then
                xRg(L).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
                xRg(L).EntireRow.Delete
                If xRg(L).Offset(0, 3).Value2 = invNo Then
                    L = L - 1
                End If
                J = J + 1
                End If
            Next
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then
               K = K - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I am learning VBA code as well and even though what you said makes perfect sense, I have no clue how to write that.... Please help

Comment: @Xtina *updated answer